# Controlling number of lines to be written to the output file

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Hadoop programming.

I have a situation in which I want to stop writing `<k3,v3>` to my output file after n-lines.

In my program, I am sure that the output file will be sorted according to `k3`, but I don't want the entire list. I only want the first n.

Is there a mechanism in Hadoop to do this?

Comment: Can you please give input -> output sample and your mapper/reducer codes.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an Class/API for the same.

But, you could increment a Counter when the [OutputCollector.collect()](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/OutputCollector.html#collect%28K,%20V%29) is called in the Reduce function. When the counter reaches the a certain value, stop calling the OutputCollector.collect().

It's a waste of CPU cycles because the reduce tasks keeps on running even after n lines are written to the o/p. There might be a better approach for the problem.

Comment: Thank you praveen. I thought of the same approach and went on to look if there is a better way.